# Laravel 4 Login Credentials mismatch does not send back error data

Tags: validation, laravel, authentication, routes

Everything is fine, Login, Validation, and Username/Password combination mismatch, except for the mismatch, it does not send back the data that I'm sending.
This is my code, and I've tried different login techniques, and same issue.

This is my blade page errors section:

```
    <div id="formErrorDiv">
        @if ($errors->has())
            <h2>* Please check your errors.</h2>
        @endif
        @if (isset($mismatch))
            <h2>* {{ $mismatch }}</h2>
        @endif
    </div>
```

while the $errors-has() for the fields' validation works perfectly, the `$mismatch` variable always turns out empty.

This is my controller login section:

```
        if($auth){
            return Redirect::intended('/');
        } else {
            //dd('auth else');
            $mismatch = 'Login Credentials Error.';
            return Redirect::route('account-sign-in')
                    ->with('mismatch', $mismatch);
        }
```

although when I use the `dd('auth else')` it does work, and so it enters the else section but always sends nothing with the redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Session::get()` to retrieve the value you pass with `with()`:

```
@if(Session::has('mismatch'))
    <h2>* {{ Session::get('mismatch') }}</h2>
@endif
```

---

`errors` is the exception here. Because it's very common to pass that to the next view, Laravel built it in so the `errors` variable from the session is automatically available in your views...

Comment: Thank you, it works. Although I tried it before, but what I did was **putting** the `$mismatch` variable in the **session** using `Session::put` and then getting it within the blade with the `Session::get` and that didn't work either. Now it's all good thanks... @lukasgeiter

Comment: But why do the `Validator` **errors** work when we use the `->withErrors()` and the `->withInput()` on the required fields?? And also I've used the `->with('variable',$variable)` before to send data and it worked, **Why not this one??**

Comment: See my answer for the explanation about `errors`. Further it's not possible to use variables sent by `with()` directly. Are you maybe referring to the use of `with()` when passing data to a view?

Comment: Yes to views. A variable or an array. It worked for example for filling a drop down list.

Comment: Well `with()` on views is something different than passing data along with a redirect.

Comment: Well the `View::make()->with()` will process the view with the data, while the `Redirect::to()->with()` will **Redirect** to a route per se **with** the data and process the route. Or how does it work?

Comment: Yes. `Redirect::to()->with()` basically does nothing else than putting the variable in your session for the next request.